# How to represent a 'string option' with ocaml config-file?

Tags: ocaml

I am using the [config-file](http://config-file.forge.ocamlcore.org/) package in Ocaml.  It looks like it should be able to represent something like a "string option", but the examples file only lists simple types, or completely custom classes.

How do I represent a simple option type using this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a pre-defined string option type. Look in section "Predefined cp classes" here: http://config-file.forge.ocamlcore.org/ocamldoc/Config_file.html

Good luck,

Comment: Something like this seems to work:

    let thing = new Config_file.option_cp Config_file.string_wrappers
      ~group:group ["defaults";"thing"] None "Thing option"

It seems to consider the empty string "" and "None" to be None.  The
Some doesn't seem to be necessary unless one wants the exact string
"Some" to be the value of the option.